# hostname -i vs hostname -I in linux

Tags: linux, networking, command-line-interface

So I looked up on google about the difference between the output for **hostname -i** and **hostname -I** but couldn't get anything significant. 
*The output for hostname -i*: `127.0.1.1`
*The output for hostname -I*: `192.168.X.X`.
All I could get was this:
-i: This option is used to get the IP(network) addresses. This option works only if the hostname is resolvable.
-I: This option is used to get all IP(network) addresses. The option doesn’t depend on the resolvability of the hostname. 
It would be great if someone could elaborate on this for me.

Answer (score 3):

From the information in your question I infer that your question is about linux `hostname` command. That's important as BSD flavor of that command (e.g. found in macOS system) has different argument set.

The man page for [linux hostname command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hostname) is actually very specific about the difference and you have posted already excerpt from it:

> ```
>   -i, --ip-address
>          Display  the  network address(es) of the host name. Note that this works only if the host name can be resolved. Avoid
>          using this option; use hostname --all-ip-addresses instead.
>   -I, --all-ip-addresses
>          Display all network addresses of the host. This option enumerates all configured addresses on all network interfaces.
>          The  loopback interface and IPv6 link-local addresses are omitted. Contrary to option -i, this option does not depend
>          on name resolution. Do not make any assumptions about the order of the output.
> ```

The "address being resolved" (the `-i` argument) means that it is being resolved via DNS. You can get similar results by using some name resolution command as `nslookup <yourhostname>` or `getent hosts <yourhostname>`:

```
$ nslookup myhostname
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    myhostname
Address: X.X.X.X
```

The `-I` on the other hand iterates over all network interfaces of your host and sees how they are actually configured. That means it obtains the IP address via completely different method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your hostname is set to `myhost`, `hostname -i` tries to resolve `myhost`. You probably have such a line in your `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       myhost
```

This will resolve `myhost` as `127.0.0.1`.

With `hostname -I` you get the addresses of your network interface(s), apparently without the loopback addresses. These addresses might be assigned by DHCP.

In your case with the output `192.168.X.X` you only have one interface connected with only an IPv4 address.

My Ubuntu 19.10 system displays one IPv4 address and one IPv6 address when connected to WiFi only or two IPv4 and IPv6 addresses each when connected to both WiFi and Ethernet.